# Can Sombra teleport to her teleporter after respawn?

Tags: overwatch

A teleporter thrown by Sombra will last for 15 seconds, a respawn generally lasts 10 seconds.

Can you throw a teleporter, die, respawn and instantly teleport back in to the fight? Or does the teleporter get removed when you die?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No. The teleporter disappears when you die.

Comment: [You can see in my pro skill level clip here that it disappears right after I die](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtlZKF3a2Uo&t=2m12s)

Comment: How OP would that be if you could do that. Teleport. Throw. Die. Repeat.